# what arg can I use instead of `*args` in child (multiple-inheritance) instance?

Tags: python, class, multiple-inheritance

what *arg* can I use instead of `*args` in the child instance? For example in this code:

```
class Foo:
    class_var = 'bar'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = 'baz'

class Test(Foo):
    def __init__(self, instance_var):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "duck"

child1 = Test(Foo) 
print("child1.instance_var: ", child1.instance_var)
```

The output is:

```
child1.instance_var:  baz
```

..but when I create the next child, the script works only when I change `def __init__(self, instance_var):` to `def __init__(self, *args):`. Without that I get "**TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance_var'**".

This code works:

```
class Foo:
    class_var = 'bar'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = 'baz'

class Test(Foo):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "duck"

child1 = Test(Foo) 
print("child1.instance_var: ", child1.instance_var)

class Test1(Test):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Test.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "new_duck"

child2 = Test1(Test)        
print("child2.instance_var: ", child2.new_instance)
```

The output is:

```
child1.instance_var:  baz
child2.instance_var:  new_duck
```

But, this one doesn't:

```
class Foo:
    class_var = 'bar'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = 'baz'

class Test(Foo):
    def __init__(self, instance_var):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "duck"

child1 = Test(Foo) 
print("child1.instance_var: ", child1.instance_var)

class Test1(Test):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        Test.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "new_duck"

child2 = Test1(Test)        
print("child2.instance_var: ", child2.new_instance)
```

I don't understand fully why (where should I place `instance_var` so the code won't throw an error). What's the logic: step by step?

Comment: A class defined as `class Test(Foo): ...` isn't supposed to be instantiated as `Test(Foo)`. Most of your problems are because you're passing `Foo` there, and you're trying all sorts of stuff to get that to work.

Comment: The idea was to create code in which class `Test` would inherit from `Foo`. Then, `Test1` from `Test`. Maybe I wasn't clear enough about that. I am practising creating classes where the classes inherit from the parent's class.

Comment: Yeah, and `class Test(Foo): ...` is correct for that, but you're not supposed to instantiate it as `Test(Foo)`.

Comment: Can you explain why? Is it because the child class doesn't have a `super` method? I'm trying to understand the whole mechanism of inheritance.

Comment: No. The stuff between the parentheses in `class Test(Foo): ...` has *nothing* to do with what goes between the parentheses when you create an instance.

Comment: I don't understand. The way to create the child class is to use `class ChildName(Parent)`. Just checked that the code can be without "**Foo**" in `child1 = Test(Foo)` and so on. But, besides that, I would like to get some feedback on how it should be built: Parent -> child(that will be a new parent for child1) -> child1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I tried to declare `instance_var` in

```
class Test(Foo):
    def __init__(self, instance_var):
```

The code works with just `self`, or with `self, *args` in a child class.

```
class Foo:
    class_var = 'bar'
    def __init__(self):
        self.instance_var = 'baz'

class Test(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "duck"

child1 = Test() 
print("child1.instance_var: ", child1.instance_var)

class Test1(Test):
    def __init__(self):
        Test.__init__(self)
        self.new_instance = "new_duck"

child2 = Test1()        
print("child2.instance_var: ", child2.new_instance)
```

That solves the problem with "**TypeError: init() missing 1 required positional argument: 'instance_var'**" when `*args` is moved.